# Node.js server to serve normal website or only for backend

Tags: node.js, heroku, hosting, web-hosting

I'm studying node.js for a new website, that will have some real time functionality, for which I will use Socket.IO. You can use node.js for both the real time functionality and serving your normal website's files, such as HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

My questions are: is it better to have them on the same host (es. Heroku), so that node.js serves the files and work as a back end server; or to have the back end functionality as a node.js server on an host and the files' server on another, dedicated, one? Which solution is usually better in term of performance? and which one is usually a cheaper solution (just in term of hosting, not for implementing the file serving in node)?

Both the website and the node.js server would not be really big.

This are the two possible solutions that came to my mind, if you use other, better, ones, feel free to suggest them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the setup simple; there's no reason to separate the two, especially given that neither half seem to be very large or sophisticated.

Comment: I agree.  If you're already running node.js for socket.io, then you should just serve the rest of the site with node.js too unless you found some specific problem with using node.js or something complicated it wouldn't do for you.